# Unpack expression results from case statement

Tags: postgresql, case

Four categories in *category* table.

```
id | name
--------------
1  | 'wine'
2  | 'chocolate'
3  | 'autos'
4  | 'real estate'
```

Two of the many (thousands of) forecasters in *forecaster* table.

```
id | name
--------------
1  | 'sothebys'
2  | 'cramer'
```

Relevant forecasts by the forecasters for the categories in the *forecast* table.

```
| id | forecaster_id | category_id | forecast                                                     |
|----+---------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1 |             1 |           1 | 'bad weather, prices rise short-term'                        |
|  2 |             1 |           2 | 'cocoa bean surplus, prices drop'                            |
|  3 |             1 |           3 | 'we dont deal with autos - no idea'                          |
|  4 |             2 |           2 | 'sell, sell, sell'                                           |
|  5 |             2 |           3 | 'demand for cocoa will skyrocket - prices up - buy, buy buy' |
```

I want prioritized mapping of *(forecaster, category, forecast)* such that, if a forecast exists for some *primary* forecaster (e.g. *'cramer'*) use it because I trust him more. If a forecast exists for some *secondary* forecaster (e.g. *'sothebys'*) use that. If no forecast exists for a category, return a row with that category and `null` for forecast.

I have something that almost works and after I get the logic down I hope to turn into parameterized query.

```sql
select
    case when F1.category is not null
        then (F1.forecaster, F1.category, F1.forecast)
    when F2.category is not null 
        then (F2.forecaster, F2.category, F2.forecast)
    else (null, C.category, null)
    end
from 
    (
        select 
                FR.name as forecaster, 
                C.id as cid, 
                C.category as category, 
                F.forecast 
        from 
                forecast F 
                inner join forecaster FR on (F.forecaster_id = FR.id)  
                inner join category C on (C.id = F.category_id)
        where FR.name = 'cramer'
    ) F1
        right join (
        select 
                FR.name as forecaster, 
                C.id as cid, 
                C.category as category, 
                F.forecast  
        from 
            forecast F 
            inner join forecaster FR on (F.forecaster_id = FR.id)  
            inner join category C on (C.id = F.category_id)
        where FR.name = 'sothebys'
    ) F2 on (F1.cid = F2.cid)
    full outer join category C on (C.id = F2.cid);
```

This gives:

```
'(sothebys,wine,"bad weather, prices rise short-term")'
'(cramer,chocolate,"sell, sell, sell")'
'(cramer,autos,"demand for cocoa will skyrocket - prices up - buy, buy buy")'
'(,"real estate",)'
```

While that is the desired data it is a record of one column instead of three. The `case` was the only way I could find to achieve the ordering of `cramer` first `sothebys` next and there is lots of duplication. Is there a better way and how can the tuple like results be pulled back apart into columns?

Any suggestions, especially related to removal of duplication or general simplification appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a case for `DISTINCT ON` (untested):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.id)
       fr.name AS forecaster,
       c.name AS category,
       f.forecast
FROM forecast f 
   JOIN forecaster fr ON f.forecaster_id = fr.id
   RIGHT JOIN category c ON f.category_id = c.id
ORDER BY 
   c.id, 
   CASE WHEN fr.name = 'cramer'   THEN 0 
        WHEN fr.name = 'sothebys' THEN 1
        ELSE 2 
   END;
```

For each category, the first row in the ordering will be picked. Since Cramer has a higher `id` than Sotheby's, it will be given preference.

Adapt the `ORDER BY` clause if you need a more complicated ranking.

Comment: I like where this goes, but the plan is to create function that takes two arguments (first: String, second: String), where in my example it would be ('cramer', 'sothebys'). There would be hundreds/thousands of forecasters and goal is some forecast for each category preferencing one forecaster. Not sure how tackle ordering. I'm open to rethinking though.

Comment: Use something like `ORDER BY c.id, CASE WHEN fr.name = arg1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`, thereby sorting entries first that match the first name.

Comment: Wow, no idea you could do that. It worked and is much more elegant. Would still like to know how to unpack that tuple, but this is great, thanks.